# Need assistance with auto menu item on scroll

Tags: jquery

I've got problem with auto menu item on scroll. Because my header has 2 menus it looks like: MENU 1 < LOGO > MENU 2; so I've been using this script:

```
// Cache selectors
var topMenu = $(".main-nav1"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   // Set/remove active class
   menuItems
     .parent().removeClass("active")
     .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
});​
```

Is it possible to somehow use 2 menus in this script? My classes are `.main-nav1` and `main-nav2`. I really need jQuery help with this, because I'm a newbie to this language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, only changing this essential line would probably be necessary :

```
menuItems = topMenu.add($('.main-nav2')).find('a'),
```

I could only see that after making it a bit more readable :

```
var topMenu = $('.main-nav1'),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
menuItems = topMenu.add($('.main-nav2')).find('a'),

scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {

    var item = $($(this).attr('href'));

    if (item.length) return item;
});

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight,

    cur = scrollItems.map(function() {

        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });

    cur = cur[cur.length-1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : '';

    menuItems
    .parent().removeClass('active').end()
    .filter('[href=#'+id+']').parent().addClass('active');
});
```